# Comparing Multi Pick List Values with a List of Strings

Tags: apex, soql

I have a custom object with a Multi Picklist field called Roles which has this list (A, B, C, D, E). Being a multi picklist, the values it returns can be A / B;E / D;E;C.

Now I have a list of strings containing (A, B). How do I know which values in the multi picklist (A / B;E / D;E;C) has at least one of the values in the list of strings (A, B). In this example, A and B;E should be a match.

This is how I was using it before but this seems to be incorrect

```
SELECT Id FROM CustomObj WHERE Roles IN :listStrings
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing. Did you debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the records and put the results into a `Map <Id, List<String>>` by iterating over the results and doing a split of the field value into a list. As you know, the values are separated by a semicolon.

Iterate over the record IDs and check if myMap.get(record.Id).contains(A) || myMap.get(record.Id).contains(B)

Do whatever you want with those records. You could put the positive case IDs into a set and then work from there, or however you'd like.